# Experiencing weird problem when deploying node app

Tags: node.js, deployment, render.com

I am trying to deploy my node project to render.com but when I do it I get the following output

```
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  sh: 1: react-app-rewired: not found
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! syscall spawn
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! file sh
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! errno ENOENT
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! openai-template@1.0.0 build: `react-app-rewired build`
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR!
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! Failed at the openai-template@1.0.0 build script.
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2022-12-23T00_21_18_486Z-debug.log
Dec 23 01:21:18 AM  ==> Build failed
```

It seems as it can't find react-app-rewired but I have it installed in my node-modules. Does anyone have a solution that might help?